# How can I get/print the JSON response from a RESTful service call in Groovy with Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: json, spring-boot, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

While implementing Spring Cloud Contract for integration testing of micro services, I have defined a Contract in Groovy and compared the expected JSON response by hard coding the values in a .json file. Everything works.

But, if I want to validate dynamically instead of having a static JSON response, I found a way but I need to get the dynamic JSON response into a string variable from the response of a REST endpoint invocation.

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {

    request {
        method 'GET'
        url '/micro-service/90640454'
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }

    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        }
        -- how can i get the actual_response here
        body (file('expected_response.json'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the `execute` method on the response side for the body

```
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {

    request {
        method 'GET'
        url '/micro-service/90640454'
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }

    response {
        status 200
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        }
        -- how can i get the actual_response here
        body ($(consumer(file('expected_response.json')), producer('assertMe($it)'))
    }
}
```

then in the base class you have to define and do the assertion in the `assertMe` method. Like this:

`public void assertMe(Object o) { ... perform assertions ... }`

If you read the documentation (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#contract-matchers) you'll find

> The type of the object read from the JSON can be one of the following, depending on the JSON path:
>
> String: If you point to a String value.
>   JSONArray: If you point to a List.
>   Map: If you point to a Map.
>   Number: If you point to Integer, Double, or other kind of number.
>   Boolean: If you point to a Boolean.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this gives me a way to proceed further... but the assertMe() method is executing twice

Comment: You have to provide more details. I don't see you screen so i can help you without any useful information

Comment: Below is my method in the base class... 
public void assertShipmentInfoByAWBResponse(Object resp) {
  try {
   System.out.println("Resp => " + resp);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Below is the Response it got printed on console... =>

2018-12-20 13:53:10.619  INFO 14400 --- [    Test worker] CommonAwbInfoServicesImpl                : doGetAwbInformation
Resp => [{"awbDetails":{"shipmentSeqNumber":1186240,"awbNumber":"90640454","carrierCode":"023"....
<br/>
Resp => [{"awbDetails":{"shipmentSeqNumber":1186240,"awbNumber":"90640454","carrierCode":"023"...

Comment: Please upload the full sample to github

Comment: Sorry the above mentioned code is not formatted... but it conveys that... the Response is printed twice... Sorry i am still doing experimenting and the project is not in a good shape to upload in Git

Comment: I can't help you without a sample

Comment: I have uploaded only the files i have created to the below Github location.
https://github.com/subhashybose/springcloudcontract-sample

Comment: Currently i have 2 concerns
1. assertShipmentInfoByAWBResponse($it) is getting invoked twice.
2. I have a complex .json file for the consumer(), but i do not want to hard code the values for each attribute/property in the json file.
    As per the documentation, i tried to give regular expressions but i am getting errors.

Comment: expected:<..."shipmentSeqNumber":[123620,"awbNumber":"12345678",

but was:<..."shipmentSeqNumber":["$(c(regex(nonEmpty()))","awbNumber":"$(c(regex(nonEmpty()))"}]}]">

Comment: I would like to generate the stubs with a generic json response format, independent of the values and types. i would like to validate only by the keys/attributes but not by the values corresponding to them. producer(execute()) is to validate from Server end, but whatever we give consumer(XYZ.json) goes into the Stubs which the clients validate against... this json which goes into Stubs i want in a generic way... so that even if client invokes the service connecting to different level(dev/test/stage), he should get successfully validated. Hope my question is clear.

Please respond. Thanks